# Battery Detected, Charging, but not Working

Tags: laptop, battery, 20.10

Ubuntu 20.10 - HP Pavilion DM4

Similar to other issues on this site but different.

Battery IS detected AND charged fully, BUT the laptop will NOT use it if AC power is disconnected.
Have replaced the battery pack as I thought the original was defective, but still the same issues. Could this be a motherboard issue or would something like a driver fix it?

Comment: I am actually in the exact same boat right now. So, following this one!

Answer (score 0):

Operating systems generally do not control when a notebook is drawing power from the battery or the AC line, as they would not react fast enough when switching between the two sources. This is 100% controlled by the hardware itself. Looking around online, the DM4 is notorious for having a really poor battery after about three years of use. The battery will show as being 100% charged but, as soon as you disconnect it, the machine will not get enough power and shut down.

What I would suggest is that you check the status of the battery by querying its firmware. This will let you know if it's time to replace the battery or not.

Here's how you can do it:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Run this command:

   ```
   upower -i `upower -e | grep 'BAT'`
   ```

   You should see something that looks like this:

   ```
     native-path:          BAT0
     vendor:               LGC
     model:                01AV494
     serial:               58
     power supply:         yes
     updated:              2021年02月10日 11時57分33秒 (36 seconds ago)
     has history:          yes
     has statistics:       yes
     battery
       present:             yes
       rechargeable:        yes
       state:               discharging
       warning-level:       none
       energy:              47.07 Wh
       energy-empty:        0 Wh
       energy-full:         51.26 Wh
       energy-full-design:  57 Wh
       energy-rate:         2.882 W
       voltage:             12.478 V
       time to empty:       16.3 hours
       percentage:          94%
       capacity:            87.4737%
       technology:          lithium-polymer
       icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
     History (rate):
       1612925853   2.882   discharging
   ```

   Compare the `energy-full` and `energy-full-design` numbers (or `capacity`, as it's a representation of these two). The first shows how much energy can be stored, which is considered 100%, and the second shows how much the battery could store at the time of manufacture. If you see that the `energy-full` value is considerably lower than `energy-full-design`, then the battery is nearing the end of its life.

   Also take a look at the `voltage` value and confirm that it is high enough to power your notebook. If the battery cannot supply enough power to the system, then it does not matter how much energy the battery might be able to store, it simply cannot supply enough of it to the machine to keep everything running. You might be able to mitigate power failures due to a weak battery by removing any USB devices, disabling wireless radios you're not using, and sticking only to integrated graphics, but this is just a temporary measure as the battery will continue to deteriorate.
2. (If Required) Buy a new battery

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The battery is a replacement that is some years old now and the energy-full/energy-full-design are nearly exactly the same. 

HOWEVER, you make a good point about the voltage. Looking at that number reads 8.158 V which could be my problem as I believe most laptops run on 12 volts.